# Submenu no funciona al usar position:absolute

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Tengo el siguiente problema, quiero hacer un submenu desplegable usando HTML y CSS pero cuando uso el `position:absolute` en el `ul` del submenu, me genera un scroll dentro del header y estoy intentando que el `ul` quede por fuera, sin ese scroll.

El código tiene más cosas pero las borré para que no se hiciera demasiado largo el código.

El problema está en el `<ul>` que usa la clase `sub-menu`

Este es el **html**:

```html
<header class="site-header">

  <h1 id="logo">Titulo</h1>

  <nav class="nav-container">
    <ul id="menu-menu-1" class="menu-principal">
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="#">Nosotros</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
        <a href="#" aria-current="page">Eventos</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="#">Info 1</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="#">Info 2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</header>
```

Y este el **css**. El problema surge a partir del comentario **SUBMENU**

```css
.site-header {
  background-color: var(--darkGrey);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.menu-principal a {
  font-family: var(--navFont);
  color: var(--white);
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  display: block;
}

nav.nav-container {
  display: none;
}

.menu-principal {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 130px;
  right: 100%;
  display: none;
  background-color: var(--darkGrey);
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: all 2s ease;

}

.site-header.fullscreen {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

nav.nav-container.active {
  display: block;
}

.menu-principal.active {
  display: block;
  left: 0%;
  height: 100%;

}

.menu-principal.active .current_page_item a {
  color: var(--colorPrimary)
}

.menu-principal.active li a:hover {
  color: var(--colorPrimary);
}

.menu-principal li a {
  display: block;
}

/**SUBMENU**/

.menu-principal ul.sub-menu {
  display: none;
}

li.menu-item-has-children:hover .sub-menu {

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  width: 150%;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes problemas, pero básicamente tu Css, NO SABES QUE LES ESTAS DICIENDO

Ya que tienes 2 contenedores en una position fixed, 1 elementos donde utilizas flexbox y otro con posición absoluta,

primero quita el flexbox, por que te darás cuenta que como css, los elementos hijo es afectado por el padre, posterior , solo 1 de tus elementos debe tener la posición de fixed, si no tu html , no sabrá que hacer , y tendrás un amontonamiento de elementos.

```
.site-header {
  background-color: var(--darkGrey);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 2rem;
}





.menu-principal {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 130px;
  right: 100%;
  display: none;
  background-color: var(--darkGrey);
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: all 2s ease;

}

.site-header.fullscreen {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
}



li.menu-item-has-children:hover .sub-menu {

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  width: 150%;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```